# How to get Last Index Of '\' or '//', whichever comes last?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, string

I want to get lastindexof  character from url which comes from the database on the basis of  '\'  or '//'

Say for example i have string like this

```
 Administration\Masters\EmployeePulseDetailsMaster.aspx
 Administration/Masters/SearchKnowYourCollegues.aspx
 Administration//SMS//PushSMS.aspx
```

I am using that code

```
foreach (var item in SessionClass.UserDetails.SubModules)
{
    if (Request.RawUrl.Contains(item.PageURL.Substring(item.PageURL.LastIndexOf('\\') + 1))
     || Request.RawUrl.Contains(item.PageURL.Substring(item.PageURL.LastIndexOf('/') + 1)))
    {
        Response.RedirectPermanent("~/Login.aspx");
    } 
}
```

Comment: i don't quite understand what your problem is?

Comment: Can't you just use the LastIndexOf method in the String class?

Comment: Have you tried `string.LastIndexOf`?  What issues are you having?

Comment: I think the question got downvotes due to a poor selection of title. I tried correcting it, and voted to reopen.

Comment: Yeah, this code looks ok. Why it isn't working properly for you?

Comment: When string have `//` or `\\` the the code is not working.

Comment: I request to everyone please help.

Comment: What is value of item.PageURL.Substring(item.PageURL.LastIndexOf('\\')? Have you checked?

Comment: I would use this instead: `string pageName = Request.Url.Segments.Last();
            bool anyMatch = SessionClass.UserDetails.SubModules.Any(u => pageName == System.IO.Path.GetFileName(u.PageURL)); `. That works with slashes and backslashes.

Comment: As @dasblinkenlight provided answer below best way will be to use regex to perform string operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want to determine if the name of the current page is in the list of `SessionClass.UserDetails.SubModules`. Then i'd use `Request.Url.Segments.Last()` to get only the name of the current page(f.e. `PushSMS.aspx`) and [`System.IO.Path.GetFileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename(v=vs.100).aspx) to get the name of each url. `GetFileName` works with `/` or `\`:

```
string pageName = Request.Url.Segments.Last(); 
bool anyMatch = SessionClass.UserDetails.SubModules
    .Any(module => pageName == System.IO.Path.GetFileName(module.PageURL)); 

if(anyMatch) Response.RedirectPermanent("~/Login.aspx");
```

You need to add `using System.Linq;` for `Enumerable.Any`.

Comment: Thanks Tim, the above answer is exactly, what i want.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regular expression to find the last occurrence of any character in a group by constructing a regular expression that looks like this:

```
[target-group][^target-group]*$
```

In your case, the target group is `[/\\]`, so the search would look like this:

```
var match = Regex.Match(s, @"[/\\][^/\\]*$");
```

Here is a running example:

```
var data = new[] {
    @"quick/brown/fox"
,   @"jumps\over\the\lazy\dog"
,   @"Administration\Masters\EmployeePulseDetailsMaster.aspx"
,   @"Administration/Masters/SearchKnowYourCollegues.aspx"
,   @"Administration//SMS//PushSMS.aspx"
};
foreach (var s in data) {
    var m = Regex.Match(s, @"[/\\][^/\\]*$");
    if (m.Success) {
        Console.WriteLine(s.Substring(m.Index+1));
    }
}
```

This prints

```
fox
dog
EmployeePulseDetailsMaster.aspx
SearchKnowYourCollegues.aspx
PushSMS.aspx
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/LPOFbT)